# Преобразование из строки в массив char

Tags: c++

Всех приветствую. Пытаюсь преобразовать из строки в массив char. Скопировал пример с одного из тонны сайтов с примерами. Ни один пример не работает, в основном ругается на такие ошибки:

1:

> Error C4996   'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe.
>   Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use
>   _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

2:

> Error (active)    E0028   expression must have a constant
>   value KeyPressesTest  D:\C++
>   Projects\KeyPress\KeyPressesTest\KeyPressesTest\KeyPressesTest.cpp    49      the
>   value of variable "n" (declared at line 46) cannot be used as a
>   constant

3:

> Error C2131   expression did not evaluate to a constant   KeyPressesTest

Код:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>


using namespace std;

// driver code 
int main()
{
    // assigning value to string s 
    string s = "geeksforgeeks";

    int n = s.length();

    // declaring character array 
    char char_array[n + 1];

    // copying the contents of the  
    // string to char array 
    strcpy(char_array, s.c_str());

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << char_array[i];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @älёxölüt Ну,здесь есть еще ошибка объявления массива с размером, неизвестным во время компиляции... Так что это не чистый дубль.

Comment: @Harry хорошо бы создавать один вопрос на одну проблему, а то так можно N проблем в одном коде собрать и возмущаться, что не дубликат. Для VLA тоже можно вопрос найти и добавить в список дубликатов, благо он расширяемый.

Comment: @älёxölüt Кто бы спорил :)